# Sass combine @forward and @use

Tags: sass

I'm trying to migrate to the new modular sass, and have two files I want to export from a common utils module:

*utils/_functions.scss*

```
@function color($key) {
  @return map-get($colors, $key);
}
```

*utils/_variables.scss*

```
$colors: (
  primary: 'red',
  secondary: 'blue',
);
```

I'm trying to export it like this:

*utils/_index.scss*

```
@forward 'variables';
@forward 'functions';
```

But I get a compilation error `SassError: Undefined variable`, because `$colors` is not defined in function.

I would like to have a way to combine `@forward` and `@use` like this:

*utils/_functions.scss*

```
@use '../variables'

@function color($key) {
  @return map-get(variables.$colors, $key);
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you have to `@use` the variables file in every file you need it. In this case you needd `utils/variables` in `utils/functions` but you do not `@use` it there.

Additional hint:

There are two additional issuses in your code, - but they do not affect the error in your question:

1. You should setup variables in modules as `!defaults` so they can be changed/overwritten when you `@use` them.
2. You have an error in your map. You setup the colors as string (= `primary: 'red'`). The result is that the value will be handeld as string and not as color which leads to a wrong css code.

Following code should work:

```
//###> file: utils/variables

$colors: (
  primary: red,
  secondary: blue,
) !default;



//##> file: utils/functions

@use 'variables' as *;

@function color($key) {
    @return map-get($colors, $key);
}



//##> file: utils/index

@forward 'variables';
@forward 'functions';



//##> file main

@use 'utils' as *; 

.class {
    color: color( primary );
}

//---> compiles to css

.class {
  color: red;
}
```